# Why Object check by key is not recognized by typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this in typescript": "3.5.2

```
enum setting02Steps {
    CSV_UPLOAD,
    CSV_EDITION,
    COMPLETED
}

enum setting02Tabs {
    TABLE,
    TREE,
    CSV
}

interface Setting02State {
    ...
    [setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION]?: {
        translates: Array<s02Translate>;
        leafs: Array<s02Leaf>;
        [setting02Tabs.CSV]?: {
            csv?: {
                name: string;
                content: csvParser.ParseResult;
            };
            loading?: boolean;
        };
    };
    ...
}
```

When I check for undefined like this :

```
if(!this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION] || !this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION][setting02Tabs.CSV]) { return; }
httpCall(''blabla, data: this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION][setting02Tabs.CSV]!.csv.content})
```

I always have to force the object with `!` or the compiler has an error on `this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION][setting02Tabs.CSV]` might be undefined even I just checked for undefined above.

Why so ?

Comment: A relevant GitHub issue is [microsoft/TypeScript#30714](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30714) but it was closed as a duplicate of another issue whose fix didn't address this.  For now I'd say this is a design limitation and you should something like [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#optional-chaining) (e.g., `this.state?.[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION]?.[setting02Tabs.CSV]?.csv?.content`) instead.  If this meets your needs I'll write up an answer; let me know

Comment: ok so it's a typescript limitation, I will write some workaround then. 

If you have a nice way to handle this in JSX template it would be nice, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically would be different in JSX... either you use the non-null assertion, optional chaining (or something similar like `(((this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION] || {})[setting02Tabs.CSV] || {}).csv || {}).content`), or intermediate variables (like `const steps = this.state[setting02Steps.CSV_EDITION]; if (!steps) return; const tabs = steps[setting02Tabs.CSV]; if (!tabs) return; const csv = tabs.csv; if (!csv) return; csv.content;`).